# How to print this pattern? Nested loops didn't work

Tags: php

How to print below square pattern in PHP?
Didn't get it to work using nested loops.

```
$add_var=0;
$k=0;
$j=1;
$row_length = 4; $column_length = 4;
for ($row = 1; $row <= $row_length; $row++)
{
    for ($column = 1; $column <= $column_length; $column++)
    {
        echo $j+$row." ";
        $add_var++;
    }
    $add_var++;
    echo "\n";
}
```

output should be :-

> 1 1 1 1
> 1 2 3 4
> 1 3 5 7
> 1 4 7 10

Comment: Hi. Can you explain what the problem is with your current solution? You will probably get better help if you explain the reason since it looks like you have working code.

Comment: No , it is not working. It is giving wrong output. can you please check this code and make it correct.

Comment: I see. Your question did not mention that, only that you did not want nested for loops. It might be useful if you also included the current output in your question.

Comment: @DarkMatter Hi , I am curious to know if we can do this with the help of only single loop ?

Comment: Since both dimensions (row and column) are variable (I assume), we will need to step through each position. It's possible that there are other methods to do this that don't require explicit for-loops (some array/list tools perhaps) but I don't know enough about PHP to do that. If one dimension is fixed size you could simply write the statements for each position. That is only feasible for smaller numbers though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your k and j variables don't do anything.

Each row starts with the number 1 so that is the base value. Then for each column you add a number which depends on which row we are on. 0 on the first row, 1 on the second and so on, so start the second loop in 0. We keep track of that value with row. Column determines how many times it is added to the base value.

I'm no PHP expert, but this should be fairly right:

```
$row_length = 4; $column_length = 4;
for ($row = 0; $row < $row_length; $row++)
{
    for ($column = 0; $column < $column_length; $column++)
    {
        $curr_val = 1 + ($column * $row);
        echo $curr_val." ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

**Edit**

Starting the row loop at 0 eliminates the need for add_var. Edited the code.

**Edit #2**

With only one loop:

```
$row_length = 4; $column_length = 4;
$r = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < row_length * column_length; i++)
{
    $mod = (i % $column_length);
    $curr_val = 1 + ($r * $mod);

    echo $curr_val." ";

    if($mod = ($column_length - 1))
    {
        echo "\n";
        $r++;
    }
}
```

(Syntax might be incorrect for PHP, I tried to convert it from Java.)

After some fixes it works. Dollar was missing from some variables.

```
 $row_length = 4; $column_length = 4;
$r = 0; 
for($i = 0; $i < $row_length * $column_length; $i++)
{
 
    $mod = ($i % $column_length);
    $curr_val = 1 + ($r * $mod);

    echo $curr_val." ";

   if($mod == ($column_length - 1))
    {
        echo "<br/>";
        $r++;
    }
}
```

Comment: can we do the same by using only one loop ?

Comment: Solved it. Loop though all positions (4x4) and calculate when to add a line break.

Comment: please correct if($mod = ($column_length - 1)), this line , it should be if($mod == ($column_length - 1))

Comment: Yes, it should be ==   Thank you @Amit Rawat for the edit

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code. It works as per you needs. It creates the pattern in one loop.

```
 $n=$limit=4; 
$j=1; 
$row=0;
$pre=1;


while($j<=$n)  {

 if($j==1) {
   echo $pre;
 } else { 
   echo $pre+$row; 
   $pre = $pre+$row;
 }
 $j++;
 
 
 if($j>$n) {
  echo '<br/>';
  $j=1;  
  $limit--; 
  $row++;  
  $pre=1;
 } 
 
 
 if($limit==0) {
   break;
 }
}
```